# ¿Para qué sirve export?

Tags: bash

Observando scripts Bash note que las variables pueden ser creadas de las siguientes formas:

`script1.sh`:

```sh
variable1=Hola
export variable2="Hola tambien"
```

Busqué saber más sobre la diferencia de estas 2 maneras formas de declarar las variables. Y por lo que entendí, `export` serviría para hacer variables globales.

Pero al excecutar el script e intentar imprimir la variable global `variable2`, obtengo el mismo resultado que la variable local de mi script `variable1`

```
$ ./script1.sh 
$ echo $variable1
$
$ echo $variable2
```

Haciendo uso del commando `source` o usando `.`  y realizando el mismo procedimiento anterior, obtengo como resultado la impresion de las 2 variables.

```
$ source script1.sh 
$ echo $variable1
Hola
$ echo $variable2
Hola tambien
```

A este punto comprendí que el propósito de `export` no es declarar variables globales.

¿Cuál es el propósito de export?

Answer (score 7):

`export` permite que la variable esté disponible para **subprocesos de la shell en ejecución**. Pone la variable en el ambiente para que otros procesos puedan hacer uso de estas.

A veces sirve para poner una ruta de configuración o una contraseña (que también es una configuración).

Por ejemplo, para indicar que tu paginador sea `less`, entonces escribes `export PAGER=less`, y cada que uses `man <programa>` en esa sesión, se usará `less` como paginador. También podría ser `most`, etc.

Te pongo un script de ejemplo para que veas qué es lo que hace `export`.

```
#!/bin/bash

export var1="Esta variable es global"
var2="Ahora si me puedes ver, perro"

principal() {

    bash -c '
    echo -e "\nEn la parte principal"
    echo "Imprimiendo \$var1: $var1"
    echo "Imprimiendo \$var2: $var2"'
}

principal
export var2  # A partir de aquí ya debería aparecer el valor de "var2"
principal
```

Cuya ejecución da:

```
$ ./export

En la parte principal
Imprimiendo $var1: Esta variable es global
Imprimiendo $var2:

En la parte principal
Imprimiendo $var1: Esta variable es global
Imprimiendo $var2: Ahora si me puedes ver, perro
```

Usé `bash -c 'etc'` para abrir un subproceso. La primera vez que se ejecuta no muestra valor alguno de la variable `var2`, pero si después de mandar a llamar `export var2`.

Answer (score 2):

@Adolfo

No vas desencaminado, si bien hay ciertos aspectos que debes diferenciar:

La manera adecuada de declarar una variable es mediante la sintaxis:

```
nombre=[valor]
```

> Un  parámetro  es una entidad que almacena valores.  Puede ser un nombre, un número, o uno de  los caracteres  especiales  listados  a  continuación  bajo  el  epígrafe  Parámetros especiales.   **En lo que se refiere al shell, una variable es un parámetro identificado por un nombre.** Un parámetro está definido si se le ha asignado un valor. La  cadena  vacía  es  un  valor válido.  Una  vez  que  una  variable  está  definida,  sólo puede quitarse de la lista de variables mediante la orden interna unset (vea ÓRDENES INTERNAS DEL SHELL más adelante).   A una variable se le puede asignar un valor mediante una sentencia de la forma nombre=[valor]   Si no se da el valor, a la variable se asigna la cadena vacía.

(Copiado del man bash).

Hay que tener presente que una variable solo existirá en la shell que se creó (es una variable local).

Diferentes son las variables globales o variables de entorno, definidas por la shell, y, que por convenio se escriben con letras mayúsculas. Ejemplos son PWD, RANDOM, o PS1:

```
alfonso@foresthost:~$ echo $SHELL  
/bin/bash
```

**Lo que la orden interna de shell export permite es convertir una variable local en global, o bien, modificar su valor en caso de que exista:**

```
alfonso@foresthost:~$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
alfonso@foresthost:~$ export PS1='(\t)[\u-\W]\$> '
(19:19:57)[alfonso-~]$>
```

En el ejemplo anterior, he modificado el promt de mi shell ( alfonso@foresthost:~$ ) por otro en que aparece la hora del sistema ( \T el tiempo actual en formato de 12 horas HH:MM:SS ), el usuario actual ( \u ) , el directorio de trabajo actual ( \W ), con algunos caracteres (paréntesis, corchetes, guión y $ tomados literalmente.

Las variables locales (que, al contrario que las globales, por convenio, se vienen definiendo en minúculas, salvo la primera letra, en mayúscula , ej MiVariableLocal) se pueden visualizar con el comando set; las variables de entorno se pueden visualizar con el comando env.

Por su parte, *source* lee y ejecuta órdenes desde el fichero al que llamas  en  el  entorno  actual  del  shell  (que ha podido ser modificado mediante *export*). El punto (.) es una manera abreviada de escribir el comando *source*.

No sé si te he liado más o te he aclarado algo; seguro que habrá quien te lo sepa explicar mucho mejor.

Suerte.

Comment: El `export PS1=foo` no hace mas que el `PS1=foo` en tu ejemplo. El `export` sería relevante solo si empezabas una otra sesión (`bash`). No hay ningun convenio que dice que las demás suelen estar en CamelCase. Mas importante, el `env` te muestra todas las variables del entorno, incluso las tuyas si las exportado. El `set` te muestra muchísimas cosas, incluso las funciones que tienes definidas. No hay variables globales. Lo que pasa es que las variables de entorno estan definidas en los ficheros de configuración que lean todas las sesiones al iniciar.

Comment: Y el ``.` no es manera abreviada de escribir `source`, es lo contrario. El `.` es la manera POSIX y el `source` es un alias por el `.` que existe en `bash`. Entonces `source` as manera alargada de escribir `.` ;)

Comment: Gracias por tus correcciones, @terdon, para mi son bienvenidas, siempre aprendiendo. Desconocía la historia de . y source

Comment: Ay, me alegro que no te lo tomaste mal! Siempre temo que aparezco agresivo ya que castellano no es mi primer idioma. Y si, yo pasé años pensando que `source` era lo 'oficial', hasta empezar pasar mas tiempo en [unix.se] donde comentarios tiquismiquis como los míos son la norma :)

Comment: Tu castellano es muy bueno. Saludos.

Comment: Sobre lo de el alias `source` de `.`, se puede encontrar más información aquí: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins
Me sorprende que no se especifique eso en `bash(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

El `export` lo necesitas solo si quieres que una variable sea accesible a los procesos que lanzas desde tu sesión:

```
$ var1="foo"
$ export var2="bar"
$ var3="baz"
$ export var3
```

Aquí, he definido tres variables y he exportado las dos (`var2` y `var3`). Esto solo para mostrar que `export var=foo` es equivalente a `var=foo` y después `export var`). Vamos a ver como funcionen:

```
$ echo "var1:$var1 var2:$var2 var3:$var3"
var1:foo var2:bar var3:baz
```

Muy bien, todas definidas en la misma sesión. ¿Pero en una sesión hija?

```
$ bash -c 'echo "var1:$var1 var2:$var2 var3:$var3"'
var1: var2:bar var3:baz
```

Aquí, ya que hemos abierto otra sesión, ella ha heredado las variables exportadas pero no `var1` que no fue exportada.

En el shell no hay realmente el concepto de variable "global". Mas bien, si que hay cuando escribes un script, pero todas las variables son globales por defecto. Si defines una en tu script, ella sera accesible a todas las funciones o otros entornos que puedas abrir al menos que la defines con `local`:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="foo"
var2="bar"

func1(){
  local var2="LOCAL!"
  var1="Cambiado!"
  echo "En la función: $var1 :: $var2"
}
echo "En el entorno normal: $var1 :: $var2"
func1
echo "Después de ejecutar la función: $var1 :: $var2"

(
  echo "En un subshel: $var1 :: $var2"
)

bash -c 'echo "En una otra sesion: $var1 :: $var2"'
```

Esto nos da:

```
$ foo.sh
En el entorno normal: foo :: bar
En la función: Cambiado! :: LOCAL!
Después de ejecutar la función: Cambiado! :: bar
En un subshel: Cambiado! :: bar
En una otra sesion:  ::
```

Ves que i) `var1` es global, entonces cambiar su valor dentro de la función, cambia su valor por fuera también. ii) `var2` y `local var2` no son la misma cosa.  El local, definido dentro de la función, solo existe dentro de ella. Fuera de la función, `var2` sigue con su valor original. iii) Finalmente, ninguna de las variables se ve en la nueva sesión ya que ninguna fue exportada.